# Java Android Dev

Tags: java, android

So this might be a stupid question but I'm new to Android Dev and can't really understand what this is. I mean, it runs just fine without that one line. But is it like a holding variable then? If someone could maybe give me an example about why this is needed or an explanation that would be great.

```
android:id="@+id/edit_message"
```

My entire code is here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirst.MainActivity" >



     <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"/> 
     <Button 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/button_send"

         />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It gives your EditText an ID so it can be referred in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is an identifier to help you get hold of your view from you code (activities and classes)

`android:id="@+id/edit_message"`

In an activity you can grab hold of this textview (if it is shown) with the following code:

```
TextView editMessage = (TextView) findByView(R.id.edit_message);
```

When you got hold of the TextView you can change is the values of it from your code e.g.

```
editMessage.setText("new text");
```

So why do we use XML when you can create all the views in your code? It is way simpler to program and it is easy to read. You can also create new XML field which dynamically adapts to the language of the system for example.

Comment: Oh ok thanks loads, one last question. If i didn't have that one line of code (android:id="@+id/edit_message") would i still be able to just read the text inside of my class?

Comment: You create GUI from the code as well, but frankly that will quite fast turn into a big mess, that is my we have XML code which simple seperates the majority of the GUI from the logic in the application.

Comment: yes, you would. The XML accually creates code, and more specificly in the TextView case, a TextView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html which you can use methods like `getText()` and `setText(String name)` on.

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it is the right one or solves your problem. :) And by the way, in the future use the tag "Android" for android specific questions, this will solve your issue faster, that's where all the Android geeks hang out to help each other. :)